# Post.order method does not work with Sequel and Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sequel

I am trying to order my posts based on the created date ( newest to oldest ) so i do this :

```
@posts = Post.order('created_at DESC')
```

But the posts are not being affected by this. What can the problem be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
@posts = Post.order(:created_at)
```

This way you order your data according to the created_at property

and if you want reversed order then

```
@posts = Post.order(:created_at).reverse
```

Comment: (http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/documentation.html)

Check the documentation in the above link 
It is very helpful ;)